# control the execution of events in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm using "onkeydown" event to implement an OTP verification layout , so when I try to delete the event first focuses on the previous element before deleting the current element , how di I get the event to execute the default action first the move along

```js
inputField[index].onkeydown = function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == "8") {
    array[index].blur();
    array[index - 1].focus();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but: You don't need to manually blur one element to be able to focus another.

Comment: The question requires too much guesswork.  Please include enough html and code to understand and reproduce the problem.